# Now there arose a new king over Egypt

Tags: discussion

I have promised to keep my activity on SE on hold until the situation with Monica's firing and slander resolved itself. This has now happened, and I find the resolution unsatisfactory. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341079/386257) is what I think on the matter, in detail.

I am therefore leaving. You will find me at the new writing community on Codidact, [here](https://writing.codidact.com/). Rather than saying goodbye, come, join me there.

(Title quote is from Exodus chapter 1)

Comment: What's important is that we're all in touch.  I'm glad you're sticking with Writing, even if it's not Writing.SE.  See you on Codidact.

Comment: I dunno man, I've seen people perma-banned for even mentioning a separate off-site chat that exists, who is this type of post still ok?